# JavaScript : Display password for a short time

Tags: javascript, events, passwords, visibility

I would like to toggle password visibility in javascript. But I would it to appear in such a way that when the user clicks on the eye icon just once, the password visibility comes as a flash and reverts back to being invisible, (i.e in the dots notation). This mechanism is implemented when trying to view wi-fi password in windows 10. I would like to use the same technique with javascript but I've been stuck around this for some time now. *DISCLAIMER: I'm now learning event types in javascript, please provide beginner friendly solution.*
Thanks in advance.

HTML Code

```
<input type="password">
        <i class="far fa-eye"></i>
```

JavaScript Code

```
let inputObj = document.querySelector("input");
let iObj = document.querySelector("i");

    iObj.addEventListener("click",function(){
       inputObj.type = (inputObj.type==="password") ? "text" : "password";
        iObj.classList.toggle("fa-eye-slash");  
    })
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try to use `setTimeout()` function.
Here's how you use it:
`setTimeout(callback, timeout-in-ms)`

Here's how it would look like:

```js
    iObj.addEventListener("click",function(){
       inputObj.type = "text";
       iObj.classList.toggle("fa-eye-slash");  

       setTimeout(() =>
         inputObj.type = "password";
         iObj.classList.toggle("fa-eye-slash");   

         // Let's say timeout for 2 seconds
       }, 2000)
    })
```